# What do people mean when they say building a stack or full stack in javascript and how does it relate to Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js. I have been learning how to use the language and still do not see the point of it. I am familiar with javascript/jQuery and angular but don't see how Node can help me with anything yet. All of the explanation mention that it is a choice made when building out the stack in full stack javascript...which confused me even more! Now what is full stack javascript and what is node. Please someone explain this in the most dummified way possible.

Comment: _node.js_ is **not** a language, it is an _environment_. _node.js_ is able to run scripts that where written in JavaScript (language). jQuery and angular are _frameworks_ written in JavaScript. Stack: everything you need for your project to run it.  A Stack for a website:  client side programming (js, css, html, ...), serverside (nodejs, php, database, ....), the server itself  and various other logic. The point of using nodejs and not e.g. php (_caution option-based:_) you only work with one language when you develop your webapplication/website.

Answer (score 2):

So, node.js is just javascript pulled out of the browser and has a few APIs attached to it. How exactly they did that, is another discussion. Node.js in short, is Chrome's V8 engine used to run your Javascript pulled outside of the Chrome browser and left to run as a stand-alone program. Some people, use it to run a web-server, other use it to run some scripts, and pretty much any other normal thing you can run with other languages (not that different from what you can do with python installed on your computer). The advantage is that you can now run JavaScript on both your browser and outside of it. Instead of learning Python/PHP/Ruby etc to run your web-server, you now just learn JavaScript. To be a full-stack JS dev means you can now code both server and front-end in JavaScript.

Side note, if you are *just* starting out as a beginner in JavaScript, please learn it as it is without worrying about node.js or whatnot. Just understand the main ideas around JS before getting ahead of yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So basically nodeJs runs your javascript when your site is not up? Therefore it's always running/updating your page without refreshing?

Comment: @user3726872  If you use _node.js_ server-side for your website then  **node.js + javascript**  is like **apache +  php**, instead that you code your page using _php_  you use _javascript_. The protocol that is use for client(browser) <-> server(nodejs)  communication is still _http_  and as of that stateless and the browser does not know that javascript is use on there server to create the page. So to your question:  `Therefore it's always running/updating your page without refreshing`: **no**.